# error while deploying jersey webapp in jetty server

Tags: maven, jersey, jetty

Getting error while deploying jersey webapp in jetty server but the application is working fine in tomcat server. Can any one help me out with this.

```
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
Jan 12, 2016 11:45:05 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/o
r provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.core.provider
.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAnd
Properties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.core.provider
.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAnd
Properties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.core.provider
.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAnd
Properties) at parameter at index 0

599095 [Scanner-0] WARN  BOLlookupRESTService  - unavailable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170
)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(We
bApplicationImpl.java:770)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(We
bApplicationImpl.java:765)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(Servle
tContainer.java:489)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComp
onent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.j
ava:605)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.j
ava:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletCon
tainer.java:374)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletCon
tainer.java:557)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.jav
a:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:27
6)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.ja
va:779)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletC
ontextHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1212)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandle
r.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453
)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(Stan
dardStarter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:1
83)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentM
anager.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.j
ava:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(Scan
ningAppProvider.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(Sc
anningAppProvider.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:348)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you  have any space in the folder names  in your workspace location at times in jersy if we have spaces in the folder name or workspace we get these kinds of error.